# ASP.NET Validators, Validate in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have a page with textboxes where a user enters their name and address. I also have ASP.NET `requiredfieldvalidators` associated with each of the input textboxes to verify that they enter in their info.  Everything works for validating the fields from C# server-side, however, I need to validate them from client-side as well.  I have an `OnClientClick` and `OnClick` events tied to a button.

When the `OnClientClick` function is called, I want to verify that the `requiredfieldvalidators` are valid (i.e. user entered info into input boxes) and if so, then I am wanting to start a JS timer that will do something after a certain period of time elapses.  In the meantime, the `Onclick` server-side event fires and executes code to insert input into database.  The server-side code is executing correctly in that my `if (Page.IsValid)` is correct.

If student did not enter info into all required fields, then it is false and does not execute the rest of the code.  If student did enter all info, then inserts into DB.  However, in the client-side code, when I execute `if (Page_ClientValidate())` it ALWAYS returns true even if no fields have been filled out.

What am I missing?  I want to say if "validation is successful (i.e. all fields have been entered) then start timer, otherwise do not start timer".  Below is short snippet of my code.  So when client-side function "Test()" is called, it is always saying 'true' even when inputs are empty, but the server-side function shows `Page.IsValid` is false, stops and shows the validator messages (which are defined in server-side function during `Page_Load()`).  Why does client-side always give me true but server-side is false?

Client:

```
<%@ Page Language="c#" CodeBehind="test1.aspx.cs" AutoEventWireup="false" Inherits="test1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>xyz</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="Form1" method="post" runat="server">
        <div id="webPage">
            <h3 class="section-title" align="left">User Information</h3>

            <div class="grid-row no-padding">
                <div class="grid-col-xs-12">
                    <div class="grid-row no-padding">
                        <div class="grid-col-xs-12">
                            <div class="form-field" style="padding-bottom: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;">
                                <p><span style="color: blue;">Name on Card</span></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="grid-row no-padding"> 
                        <div class="grid-col-xs-6" style="min-width:200px;">
                            <div class="form-field">
                                <label class="formlabel">First Name:</label>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="tbBillFirstName" runat="server" CssClass="input-textbox editable" BackColor="#fff2e6"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvFirstName" ControlToValidate="tbBillFirstName" Display="Dynamic" runat="server"
                                    Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="10" Font-Bold="False" ForeColor="#ff8c19"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="grid-col-xs-6" style="min-width:200px;">
                            <div class="form-field">
                                <label class="formlabel">Last Name:</label>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="tbBillLastName" runat="server" CssClass="input-textbox editable" BackColor="#fff2e6"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvLastName" ControlToValidate="tbBillLastName" Display="Dynamic" runat="server"
                                    Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="10" Font-Bold="False" ForeColor="#ff8c19"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="grid-row no-padding">
                        <div class="grid-col-xs-12">
                            <div class="form-field" style="padding-bottom: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;">
                                <p><span style="color: blue;">Billing Address</span></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="grid-row no-padding">
                        <div class="grid-col-xs-6" style="min-width:200px;">
                            <div class="form-field">
                                <label class="formlabel">Street1:</label>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="tbBillAddress1" runat="server" CssClass="input-textbox editable" BackColor="#fff2e6"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvAddress1" ControlToValidate="tbBillAddress1" Display="Dynamic"
                                    Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="10" Font-Bold="False" ForeColor="#ff8c19" runat="server"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="grid-col-xs-6" style="min-width:200px;">
                            <div class="form-field">
                                <label class="formlabel">Street2:</label>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="tbBillAddress2" runat="server" CssClass="input-textbox editable" BackColor="#fff2e6"></asp:TextBox>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="grid-row no-padding">
                        <div class="grid-col-xs-6" style="min-width:200px;">
                            <div class="form-field">
                                <label class="formlabel">City:</label>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="tbBillCity" runat="server" CssClass="input-textbox editable" BackColor="#fff2e6"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvBillCity" ControlToValidate="tbBillCity" Display="Dynamic" runat="server" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="10" Font-Bold="False" ForeColor="#ff8c19"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="grid-col-xs-6" style="min-width:200px;">
                            <div class="form-field">
                                <label class="formlabel">State:</label>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="StatesDDL" runat="server" DataTextField="State_name" DataValueField="State_code" CssClass="input-textbox editable" AutoPostBack="False" BackColor="#fff2e6"></asp:DropDownList>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvBillState" ControlToValidate="StatesDDL" Display="Dynamic" InitialValue="Select" runat="server" Font-Name="Arial" Font-Size="10" Font-Bold="False" ForeColor="#ff8c19"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="grid-row no-padding">
                        <div class="grid-col-xs-6" style="min-width:200px;">
                            <div class="form-field">
                                <label class="formlabel">Zip:</label>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="tbBillZip" runat="server" CssClass="input-textbox editable" BackColor="#fff2e6"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvBillZip" ControlToValidate="tbBillZip" Display="Static"
                                    runat="server" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="10" Font-Bold="False" ForeColor="#ff8c19"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                <asp:CustomValidator ID="cvZip" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="10" Font-Bold="False"
                                    ForeColor="#ff8c19" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="tbBillZip"
                                    OnServerValidate="CheckZipFormat"></asp:CustomValidator>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="grid-col-xs-6" style="min-width:200px;">
                            <div class="form-field">
                                <label class="formlabel">Country:</label>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCountry" runat="server" DataTextField="Country_name" DataValueField="Country_code"
                                    OnSelectedIndexChanged="CountryChanged" AutoPostBack="True"
                                    CssClass="input-textbox editable" BackColor="#fff2e6">
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvCountry" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ddlCountry"
                                    Display="Dynamic" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="10" Font-Bold="False"
                                    ForeColor="#ff8c19" InitialValue="00"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <div id="divSubmit" class="grid-row bottom-nav">
            <div class="grid-col-xs-12" style="text-align:center;">
                <asp:LinkButton ID="btn_submit2" runat="server" OnClientClick="Test();" OnClick="btn_submit_Click" CssClass="button button-orange" CausesValidation="true">Submit</asp:LinkButton>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function Test() {
                if (Page_ClientValidate()) {
                    alert('valid');
                }
                else {
                    alert('not valid');
                }
            }
        </script>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Server-side:

```
public void btn_submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsValid)
    {
        // insert into DB
    }
}
```

Comment: Shot in the dark, but should you use double quotes inside your alert('valid') statements?

Comment: Please refactor that text into something readable.